# Combining fig.legend with subfigures in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

**Disclaimer:** I am aware that using subfigures is irrelevant in this simple example, the latter is used only to show my problem: I want to be able to use `fig.legend()` with `fig.subfigures1`.

---

I am currently discovering the new [subfigure](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html) module of matplotlib. I noticed that figure legends created using `fig.legend()` does not show up when the main figure contains subfigures:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y1 = x
y2 = -x

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
subfigs = fig.subfigures(nrows=2, ncols=1)

for subfig in subfigs:
    axarr = subfig.subplots(1, 2)
    for ax in axarr.flatten():
        l1, = ax.plot(x, y1, label='line1')
        l2, = ax.plot(x, y2, label='line2')
            #
        ax.legend()
    # subfig.legend(handles=[l1, l2], loc='upper center', ncol=2)
fig.legend(handles=[l1, l2], loc='upper center', ncol=2)
plt.savefig('subfigures_figlegend.png', dpi=200)
```

[image]

Note how that figure legend is absent. For comparison, note that is shows up when using only `plt.subplots`:

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2, constrained_layout=True)
for ax in axarr.flatten():
    l1, = ax.plot(x, y1, label='line1')
    l2, = ax.plot(x, y2, label='line2')
    #
    ax.legend()
fig.legend(handles=[l1, l2], loc='upper center', ncol=2)
plt.savefig('subplots_figlegend.png', dpi=200)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When I ran your code the legend was there, but it was behind and slightly above the plot, and then cut off when `plt.savefig()` is called. I was able to get it to work with the `bbox_inches='tight'` argument of `plt.savefig()` and the following to move the legend.

```
fig.legend(handles=[l1, l2], bbox_to_anchor=(0.7, 1.1), ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Good catch, I will fire a bug report on this, I am pretty sure it is not an intended behaviour. Still, note that `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: savefig() got unexpected keyword argument "box
_inches" which is no longer supported as of 3.3 and will become an error two minor releases later`

Comment: And I haven;t figured out a way yet to correct this zorder problem, changing the legend zorder afterwards with `l.set_zorder(1000)
` does not change anything

Comment: @Liris box_inches is a typo. It should be bbox_inches

Comment: I don't see any `bbox_inches='tight'` argument in `fig.legend(handles=[l1, l2], bbox_to_anchor=(0.7, 1.1), ncol=2)`. Don't comment about typos: Edit your post.

Comment: It’s not in fig.legend, it’s passed to the call to savefig. I edited the post for clarity.