# Can't adjust subplot to make room for legend below

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

I want to add a centered, common legend below a figure that has been modelled on [the answer to an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68209152/1307851).

To do this, I try first make room for the legend with `fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)` and then add the legend. But `subplots_adjust()` doesn't seem to do anything. This I presume results in the legend being hidden behind the subplots. (The legend shows up just fine if I set `loc="upper right"`.)

To be clear, I'm not married to the idea of using `subplots_adjust()`. I just want to add a common legend that is centered below this figure.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
fig.suptitle('Figure title')

x = np.arange(3)
width = 0.25
subfigs = fig.subfigures(nrows=3, ncols=1)
for row, subfig in enumerate(subfigs):
  subfig.suptitle(f'Subfigure title {row}')
  axs = subfig.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
  for col, ax in enumerate(axs):
    ax.bar(x, 2 * (x + 0.5), width, label="One")
    ax.bar(x + width, 3 * (x + 0.5), width, label="Two")
    ax.set_title(f'Plot title {col}')

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)  # Doesn't seem to do anything
handles, labels = axs[0].get_legend_handles_labels()
fig.legend(handles, labels, ncol=len(handles), loc='lower center')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Same issue as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397312/combining-fig-legend-with-subfigures-in-matplotlib